# Использование "с тех пор, как"

Tags: предлоги

У меня возникли сомнения по поводу использования фразы *с тех пор, как*.

Представим ситуацию, что мы рассказываем историю про женщину, которая когда-то ходила на могилу мужа. Она больше на неё не ходит (неважно по каким причинам), корректно ли использовать слова "с тех пор, как" или же они всегда подразумевают, что что-то длится до момента речи? Если да, то, наверное, нужно сказать "После того, как он умер/ После его смерти"

> Она ходила на его могилу каждые выходные с тех пор, как он умер.

Что я имею в виду под моментом речи:
"Я живу здесь *с тех пор, как* переехал." Действие продолжается до сих пор.

Answer (score 2):

*С тех пор как* даёт начало некоему отсчёту событий/моментов. От забора до заката, - помните?

То есть *с тех пор как* требует либо начального, либо конечного (позиционно в предложении) уточнения *что происходит*.

Вот глуповато-грубоватые примеры, но языково они безупречны:

*Она перестала ходить на могилу мужа, с тех пор как встретила нового спутника жизни.*

*Она перестала ходить на могилу мужа с тех пор, как встретила нового спутника жизни* (то же, но с перестановкой запятой).

*С тех пор как женщина встретила нового спутника жизни, она перестала ходить на могилу мужа.*

Не усматриваю конструкционной напряжёнки.

Answer (score 1):

«Она ходила на его могилу каждые выходные». «С тех пор, как он умер» — совершенно лишняя добавка: какая же может быть могила, если человек не умер?!